# PHP: store html form input into php variable

Tags: php, html, forms

I like to store an input of a HTML form into a PHP variable:

**HTML Form:**

```
<form action="shell.php" method="post">
 <p>Youtube Link: <input type="text" name="url" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

**PHP File (shell.php)**

```
<?php
value=<?php echo ($_POST['url']); ?>;
exec('/bin/bash /home/d_youtube/youtube.sh "$value"');
?>
```

How I can store the input of the HTML form into the php variable **$value**?

Thanks for your help, best regards

Comment: Use your favorite Internet search engine to look up something like "php form processing"

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to open another PHP tag. Replace your code to below:

```
<?php
   $value = $_POST['url']; 
   exec('/bin/bash /home/d_youtube/youtube.sh "$value"');  
?>
```

And if you want to verify the value is not empty:

```
 <?php
   if (isset($_POST['url'])) {
      $value = $_POST['url'];   
      exec('/bin/bash /home/d_youtube/youtube.sh "$value"');
   }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify the file itself. You just can pass the input VALUE to the required expression:

Check this:

```
<?php
if( !empty($_POST['url']) )
    exec('/bin/bash /home/d_youtube/youtube.sh "' . $_POST['url'] . '"');
?>
```